# Querying a number from a range in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Say I have an item with range in it:

```
item.rb
:min_age # 3
:max_age # 7
:type
:available
```

Now I have to display an item from a certain range.

Currently I am doing this:

```
Item.where(type: item_type.singularize.capitalize, available: true, min_age: age)
```

However I would like to display items from within min_age..max_age range. Tried it with conditions, but apparently not doing it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Item.where(type: item_type.singularize.capitalize, available: true).where("min_age > ?", age).where("max_age < ?", age)
```

I think this will work.

Comment: is it possible to use one 'where'?

Comment: Yes yuo can use where any number of times.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `where` in @MKumar's answer like:

```
Item.where("type = ? && available = ? && min_age > ? && max_age < ?",item_type.singularize.capitalize,true,age,age)
```